# jQuery: load html file containing css stylesheet using html mimetype

Tags: jquery, css, mime-types

```
    $.get("page/test.thml", function(html){
        $("#iframe").contents().find("html").html(html);
    },'html')
```

test.html contains css stylesheet.

but I get `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:`

the html loads but its missing it's css styling. I tried to copy paste the css file contents into the html file itself but this did not fix the issue.

how to make the css display when the html is loaded?

Comment: have you added type="text/css" in your stylesheet link when adding to html file..?

Answer (score 0):

Please find below solution.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Your HTML Physical file path here// Note: style should have text/css attribute.
            $("#result").load("YourHTML.html", function () {
                alert($("#result").html()); // This is your HTML
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: this gives me `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: html>`

Comment: Hope you have placed Scripts/jquery.js Also, if possible you could post your html over here. I've tested same over my system and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#result").load("file.html");
});
```

It will load you html including your css styling automatically(HTML with embedded CSS). But if you set the mapping addresses of the css file(Linked CSS case) in the html file in the right way it will be no problem.

Comment: exactly the same `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:`

Comment: The priciples is browsers make HTTP requests to servers. Then server makes an HTTP response. If you have declare html headers, the Content-Type will identifying the body's elements is a HTML tag or not. If you have already check your MIME type and text/css is already on css and it still not working that means there are something else about your server is making that stylesheet come with the wrong content-type. I recommend you to use the Net tab of your browser's developer tools to examine the request and the response.

Comment: Have you check for your .htaccess? make sure to mention that this error will giving you only in subdirectory and only after a page refresh